# SelectField - change popover color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to change the `SelectField`'s popover background color in [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/)?

I checked in the generated theme but there's no `selectField` or `popover` key. Tried changing `menu`'s `backgroundColor` and `containerBackgroundColor` but it had no effect on the `SelectField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Behind the scenes `SelectField` uses the `DropDownMenu` component and you can see [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu) there is a property **menuStyle** - that's what you're gonna use to change the popover style.
Example:

```
<SelectField menuStyle={{background: '#ddd'}} ...otherProps >
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't get the reasoning behind having two components that are so similar, though.